# Why is ng-model=$scope.model undefined, if I put it in a ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can someone guide me? When I put `$scope.nameStaff` in `ng-repeat`, its value is `undefined`. I don't understand why the value is `undefined`.

This is my code:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="form in form">
<input type="text" ng-model="nameStaff" />
<input type="text" ng-model="idStaff" />
<button ng-click=addDetail()>add
</button>1
</div>
{{form}}
</div>



var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.form = [{
    companyName: "company1",
    companyAddress: "company address",
    staff: [{
      name: "men",
      id: "123"
    }]
  }, {
    companyName: "company1",
    companyAddress: "company address",
    staff: [{
      name: "men",
      id: "123"
    }]
  }]
  $scope.addDetail = function() {
    alert($scope.nameStaff);
    $scope.form[0].staff.push({
      name: $scope.nameStaff,
      id: $scope.idStaff
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Check [the `ngRepeat` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). Each loop of `ngRepeat` gets its own scope. If this were not the case, how would your `addDetail` method know which `nameStaff` you were referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want (although, I have no idea why you would want this):

```
<!-- don't refer to children with the same name as parents -->
<div ng-repeat="f in form">
    Staff Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="f.staff.name" /> <br />
    Staff Id:
    <input type="text" ng-model="f.staff.id" />
    <button type="button" ng-click="addStaff(f.staff)" />
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$scope.addStaff = function(staff) {
    var staffName = staff.name;
    var staffId = staff.id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.form = [{
        companyName: "company1",
        companyAddress: "company address",
        staff: [{
            name: "men",
            id: "123"
        }]
    }, {
        companyName: "company1",
        companyAddress: "company address",
        staff: [{
            name: "men",
            id: "123"
        }]
    }]
    $scope.addDetail = function() {
        alert($scope.nameStaff);
        $scope.form[0].staff.push({
            name: $scope.nameStaff,
            id: $scope.idStaff
        });
    }
}

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="f in form">
        <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.nameStaff" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.idStaff" />
        <button ng-click=addDetail()>add
        </button>
    </div>
    {{form}}
</div>
```

You can used '$parent.nameStaff'.